# Automatic creation of value within document (like a trigger? or auto increment value?)

Tags: mongodb

I'm sure I read some where in the latest book that you can automatically set a value to be created within a document upon creation, server side. I'm sure it was in relation to indexes.. But I can't find it!

That is to say, if a document is inserted, MongoDB itself takes the initiative to create the value.

Obvious solution is to have the value created application side - but to cut a long story short, in this particular instance that is strictly not possible. And I would not be asking this question, had I not had an inkling I had read it could be done server side.

I've also reviewed auto increment values, but my value needs to always be 0 and furthermore I appear to not be able to do it without totally replacing the _id value (?).

Another option is to have a server side script, outside of MongoDB, that when seeing a new document updates it to have the value. But wanted to see if MongoDB had something in built.

tl;dr can MongoDB automatically create a value within a document upon creation? Or did I imagine reading this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no triggers in mongo (but you can vote for the feature here -> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124).

Answer (score 0):

#### Default values

As at MongoDB 2.4, there is no server-side support to set default values for arbitrary fields when a document is inserted without specifying those field values in your insert/upsert. This implies some sort of schema validation or server-side triggers, and neither of these are currently MongoDB features (or near-term likely, IMHO).

If you insert a document without an `_id` field (the required primary key for a document), the client driver will generate an [`ObjectID`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for this. If the application or driver do not provide an `_id`, as a last resort the MongoDB server will generate a new `ObjectID`.

#### `$setOnInsert` operator

If you are doing [`upserts`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) (update if document exists, otherwise insert a new one), there is a [`$setOnInsert` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) which *may* be what you read about. With this operator you can provide a default value for a field when an upsert results in an insert. This is still done on the application side, though.

#### If you are determined to fake it

Since you've mentioned that for some reason you **can't** modify the application code, here are a few possible workarounds. To be clear, these still involve writing application code but get around your limitation of not changing the original application code (which **definitely** is the most direct and robust approach).

1. Write a script that finds documents in your collection missing the required field (using [{ $exists: false }](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)) and updates those with your desired default. You can run this as a scheduled job (i.e. using `cron` on Linux) and adjust the frequency depending on how immediately you need the default field to exist.
2. If you need the default value to be added in a more "real-time" fashion you can potentially use a [Tailable Cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/). This would involve configuring your MongoDB deployment as a replica set (if it isn't already) so that an `oplog` is created. You would have to write custom code to tail the oplog and inspect relevant inserts to see if they are missing the default field (and updating as necessary). There is a [Mongo Connector](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector) which may be a helpful starting point.